# Linha horizontal no VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, tela

Oi hoje pela noite apareceu uma linha horizontal preta no meu VSCode. Ela aparecia toda vez que eu rolava pra baixo ou para cima. Eu devo ter ativado algo sem querer.Isso tá incomodando. [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL8uz.jpg)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Tem uma imagem no final da dúvida que mostra o problema, alguém respondeu que era só desativar a opção "Stick Scroll" e funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score -4):

Você pode clicar com o botão direito do mouse e desativar a opção "sticky scroll"